# Problema com vetor com alocação dinâmica

Tags: c, array, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

A intenção desse programa que eu tô fazendo é servir como se fosse um sistema bancário em que a quantidade de contas a serem criadas não tenham uma quantia previamente definida. No `main()`, eu chamo a função `inserir()`, e imprimo logo em seguida pra ver se ela tinha funcionado. O que não foi o caso.

O programa roda mas trava quando coloco pra imprimir. O que pode estar errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int ler_dados(){
    int cod;

    printf("Digite o codigo:");
    scanf("%d",&cod);

    return cod;
}

void inserir(int *cod, float *saldo, int *TAM){
    int conta;

    conta = ler_dados();

    cod = (int*) malloc(sizeof(conta)*(*TAM));
    saldo =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*(*TAM));
    cod[*TAM-1] = conta;
    saldo[*TAM - 1] = 0;
    *TAM++;
}

int main (void){
    float *saldo;
    int *cod, TAM,i;

    TAM = 1;

    for (i=0; i<TAM; i++) {
        inserir(cod, saldo, &TAM);      

        printf("Vetor");

        for (i=0; i<TAM; i++) {
            printf("%d",cod[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Cara, a intenção desse programa que eu tô fazendo é servir como se fosse um sitema bancário em que a quantidade de contas a serem criadas não tenham um uma quantia previamente definida. No main, eu chamo a função inserir, e printo logo em seguida pra ver se ela tinha funcionado. O que não foi o caso. Deveria ter específicado melhor, primeira vez postando algo aqui, paciência.

Comment: Aí é muito mais complexo que isso, até dá pra fazer de forma simplificada, mas seria aprender errado, e esta forma feita, além de dar um erro, ela é inadequada, e causa outros problemas que não são erros visíveis, mas que está errado. E vai fazer isso infinitamente?

Comment: Erulos, sempre é possível **[edit]** a pergunta colocando mais detalhes e deixando-a mais clara :-)

Comment: Pode me dizer o que eu devo estudar pra conseguir fazer isso? O que eu quero é um sitema bancário simples, "saque", depósito e excluir conta. A questão toda seria essa parte do vetor

Comment: hkotsubo  fiz isso no tópico, e caramba. Você editou o meu post muito rápido, vi que tava bugado, fui editar e quando terminei. Vi que você já tinha mexido. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia toda está errada, melhorei algumas coisas e deixei outras de lado.

Se existe uma entidade conta bancária deveria criar um tipo para lidar com isto, não deve lidar com os membros disto isoladamente como se fossem coisas isoladas.
Usei nomes mais significativos e dentro do padrão normal de nomenclatura, mantendo tudo em minúsculo e usando o vetor no plural para deixar claro que ali tem vários elementos.

Inicializei o vetor na `main()` e liberei a memória no final, ainda que neste caso não precise porque ele está acabando mesmo.

Fiz um controle do tamanho de forma mais simples, evite passar coisas por referência sem necessidade. E usei o tamanho como gatilho para encerrar o cadastro, no código original era infinito.

Usei o `realloc()` para mudar a alocação de local. Isto não é o ideal, mas é melhor que ir alocando novos vetores e abandonar sujando a memória o que criaria problemas futuros. Eu mantive acrescendo de um em um, mas isto não é correto, deveria alocar um número de itens mínimo inicial e ir pelo menos dobrando de tamanho a cada vez que faz a relocação, mas precisaria fazer a relocação só quando a capacidade estiver toda preenchida, senão poderia ser até pior. Como já tem tamanho e capacidade o mais correto seria ter um tipo que abstraísse o vetor de contas com esses elementos, aliás isso é o que se faz em código real, eu só não quis mudar demais o código.

Quero lembrar que `float` não é adequado para guardar valor monetário, mas deixei por ser um exercício e iriam complicar fazer certo. Mas tenha isso em mente quando for fazer algo real.

Dei uma limpada no código. Não é o ideal, para para exercício acho que está bom pra ter uma ideia.

O código provavelmente não deveria ser digitado e sim pego de uma fonte atômica.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int codigo;
    float saldo;
} Conta;

int ler_dados() {
    int cod;
    printf("Digite o codigo:");
    scanf("%d", &cod);
    return cod;
}

int inserir(Conta *contas, int tamanho) {
    int codigo = ler_dados();
    if (codigo == 0) return tamanho;
    contas = realloc(contas, sizeof(int) * (tamanho + 1));
    contas[tamanho].codigo = codigo;
    contas[tamanho].saldo = 0;
    return ++tamanho;
}

int main (void) {
    Conta *contas = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int tamanho = 0;
    while (1) {
        int retorno = inserir(contas, tamanho);
        if (retorno == tamanho) break;
        tamanho = retorno;
    }
    printf("Vetor\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) printf("%d\n", contas[i].codigo);
    free(contas);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Vector2.c).

Há um problema neste código, veja mais em [Problema com alocação dinâmica - realloc()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326686/101).

Comment: Como funciona esse `while (1)`?

Comment: É infinito., sempre verdadeiro.