# Problema com alocação dinâmica - realloc()

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Estou fazendo um programa que funcione como um sistema de folha de pagamento, mas estou com problemas na parte da alocação dinâmica. O programa executa apenas uma vez e para. No `int(main)` eu coloquei:

```
    printf("Sizeof : %d\n",sizeof(funcionarios));
    printf("Executou: %d\n",i+1);
    printf("Tamanho: %d\n\n",tamanho);
```

Pra tentar identificar onde estava o erro. Na segunda execução o `sizeof()` retorna o mesmo valor o que me levou a crer que o `realloc()` não realocou a memória. Posso estar errado, estou aprendendo ainda. Peço ajuda a alguém mais esclarecido que eu.

Código completo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct{
    int matricula;
    float salario;
}Funcionario;

int ler_dados(void){
    int dado;
    printf("Digite a matrícula:\t");
    scanf(" %d",&dado);
    return dado; 
}
float ler_salario(void){
      float salario;
      printf("Digite o valor do salário:\t");
      scanf(" %f",&salario);
      return salario;
}
int inserir_funcionario(Funcionario *funcionarios, int tamanho){
    int qntd = sizeof(funcionarios) * (tamanho + 1);
    funcionarios = realloc(funcionarios, qntd);
    funcionarios[tamanho].matricula = ler_dados();
    funcionarios[tamanho].salario = ler_salario();
    tamanho++;
    return tamanho;
}
int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int i;
    Funcionario *funcionarios = malloc(sizeof(funcionarios));
    int tamanho = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Sizeof : %d\n",sizeof(funcionarios));
        printf("Executou: %d\n",i+1);
        printf("Tamanho: %d\n\n",tamanho);
        tamanho = inserir_funcionario(funcionarios, tamanho);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro foi até meu na sua pergunta anterior. Eu foquei no problema principal e deixei passar outro erro. Mas lembro que ficar relocando desse jeito continua sendo inadequado como falei antes, e este novo problema é fruto disso. Complica muito. O gerenciamento de memória deveria ser tratado de uma forma isolada e preferencialmente no mesmo local onde a variável foi criada, fica muito mais fácil.

Este problema ocorreu porque está passando o ponteiro da memória a ser tratada, e isto permite que você altere os dados que estão neste local da memória. Mas não permite você alterar o ponteiro. Até pode mudar, mas ele só será visto dentro da função onde foi alterado. Quando dá o `realloc()` ele muda o ponteiro dentro de `inserir_funcionario()`, mas fora dela o ponteiro não foi modificado, e aí começa a confusão. Na próximo execução da função ela está recebendo o ponteiro original não relocado, e em algum momento causará problema de corrupção ou até, por sorte, quebrar a aplicação.

A solução é passar até o ponteiro por referência, então acaba tendo fazer um duplo ponteiro na passagem, e tem que derreferenciá-lo para usar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct {
    int matricula;
    float salario;
} Funcionario;

int ler_dados(void) {
    int dado;
    printf("Digite a matrícula:\t");
    scanf(" %d", &dado);
    return dado; 
}
float ler_salario(void) {
      float salario;
      printf("Digite o valor do salário:\t");
      scanf(" %f", &salario);
      return salario;
}
int inserir_funcionario(Funcionario **funcionarios, int tamanho) {
    *funcionarios = realloc(*funcionarios, sizeof(Funcionario) * (tamanho + 1));
    (*funcionarios)[tamanho].matricula = ler_dados();
    (*funcionarios)[tamanho].salario = ler_salario();
    return ++tamanho;
}
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    Funcionario *funcionarios = malloc(sizeof(Funcionario));
    int tamanho = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Sizeof : %lu\n", sizeof(Funcionario));
        printf("Executou: %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Tamanho: %d\n\n", tamanho);
        tamanho = inserir_funcionario(&funcionarios, tamanho);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/b0o42U). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ahpfprns-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ReallocOnFuncion.c).

Para simplificar pode fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct {
    int matricula;
    float salario;
} Funcionario;

int ler_dados(void) {
    int dado;
    printf("Digite a matrícula:\t");
    scanf(" %d", &dado);
    return dado; 
}
float ler_salario(void) {
      float salario;
      printf("Digite o valor do salário:\t");
      scanf(" %f", &salario);
      return salario;
}
int inserir_funcionario(Funcionario *funcionarios, int tamanho) {
    funcionarios[tamanho].matricula = ler_dados();
    funcionarios[tamanho].salario = ler_salario();
    return ++tamanho;
}
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    Funcionario *funcionarios = malloc(sizeof(Funcionario));
    int tamanho = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Sizeof : %lu\n", sizeof(Funcionario));
        printf("Executou: %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Tamanho: %d\n\n", tamanho);
        funcionarios = realloc(funcionarios, sizeof(Funcionario) * (tamanho + 1));
        tamanho = inserir_funcionario(funcionarios, tamanho);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DNnN69). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vhbvdvlg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ReallocSimple.c).